# How to check if the ajax call method is POST or GET?

Tags: php, ajax

How do I check if the `TYPE` used in an `AJAX` call is `POST` or `GET` in my php page/server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
  // POST
} else {
  // GET
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the php page echo the php variable like this `echo 'post data'. $_POST['data']; echo 'get data'.$_GET['data']';`

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
     //you can see it here whether its echoing(what) or not
alert(data);
    });
```

this way you will be able to know.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you want your server side script to work with both GET and POST then you can use the `$_REQUEST` array instead of trying to find your variables in either `$_GET` or `$_POST`. `$_REQUEST` will always have the variables no matter type the call was.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
if (isset{$_POST)) {
echo 'Post Values';
} else {
echo 'Get Values';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // …
}
```

For more details please see the [documentation for the $_SERVER variable](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).